# Missing Devanagari letters in Hindi

Tags: historical-linguistics

Sanskrit and Hindi both use the Devanagari script.  It it interesting to note that there are letters which are used by only one of these languages and not the other.

Used only in Sanskrit are letters Lri, and Rii. I would request if  any example of their usage be given and also why were these letters never used in Hindi.

Comment: I haven't learnt Sanskrit, so I don't know good references to cite. On teh interwebs, people say that lri and rii were invented by Sanskrit phoneticians, as letters that *should* exist, for the sake of completeness, but apparently they are not in use in Sanskrit either, because they are difficult to pronounce.

Comment: Devanagari is used for lots of languages. Nepali and Marathi are pretty major ones. I know Marathi has at least one letter not used in Nepali. And of course it's for the same reasons Hungarian, Icelandic, or Lithuanian has extra letters not used by English - because they have extra sounds and decided an extra letter would be a good way to deal with that. (Sanskrit is also written in other scripts besides Devanagari.) ... Didn't notice this is a nice old question already (-:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all it is not completely right to say that Sanskrit and Hindi both use the Devanagari script.

It is true that Devanagari script is the native script of Hindi, which is also written in other scripts such as Urdu script and roman script (mainly in social media and Hinglish). Sanskrit, on the other hand, has no native script whatsoever and it is written in several scripts in Indian subcontinent and Southeast Asia and it has been so since ancient times. It is quite possible that two Sanskrit speakers (one from North India and second from Thailand) perfectly understand each other while talking but still not be able to understand a single letter of each other's writing.

Letters you are referring to (Lri, Rii etc.) belong to Sanskrit alphabet not the Hindi alphabet. The [Devanagari script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari) is not exclusive to Hindi and is used to write alphabets of other languages such as Marathi and Sanskrit as well. As an other example, Marathi alphabet has some letters that are not in Hindi or Sanskrit alphabets but they all use Devanagari script.

Comment: Furthermore, there are letters in Devanagari that represent sounds that don't even occur in Sanskrit, let alone Hindi, but have been posited abstractly by the gurus to use in roots, although they're always changed in words. An example is the long syllabic /l/.

Comment: This is 100% business as usual in scripts that are used for more than one language. Even scripts such as Georgian and Lao have a couple of letters not used by their namesake language but only for one or more nearby minority languages. And the Arabic, Cyrillic, and Roman scripts have loads of extra letters than what are used in Arabic, Russian, or English.

Comment: Correct. Only here we have a case where "lri and rii were *invented* by Sanskrit phoneticians, as letters that **should** exist, for the sake of completeness"...of the grammatical rules. Quite natural then that; Hindi grammar being different; these vowels had no relevance there.

Comment: Is there any other Indian language where these vowels are used ?

Comment: @ARi: The long vowel ṝ *is* used in Sanskrit, most prominently in the genitive ("6th case") plurals of ṛ-ending words: "of fathers" is pitṝṇāṃ, "of brothers" is "bhrātṝṇāṃ", etc. The long ḹ on the other hand doesn't even always appear in alphabet lists.

Comment: @Ritesh: It is **false** that long ṝ (which you write rii) is not used in Sanskrit. I already gave examples in my comment above, of very common words where it's used. The only doubtful question is whether there exists a long ḹ corresponding to (the commonly used) long ṝ, and that's what is discussed by (some) grammarians while not being attested in words. And none of this has any relevance to overlong vowels of three morae length; these are just usual long vowels of two morae length.

Comment: While it doesn't touch on the original topic, some analyses recognise overlong vowels in Estonian.

Comment: @Ritesh: You are introducing confusion by talking of accuracy of scripts now, rather than what is used in the language. What do you mean by fallen out of use?! It is simply *wrong* in Sanskrit to say bhrātṛṇāṃ for bhrātṝṇāṃ; no competent Sanskrit speaker would do it. It is *false* that the long ṝ is not used in Sanskrit. You have no source for the claim, and the source you used does not say so, and still you persist in it.

Comment: @Ritesh: Secondly, the fact that the original pronunciation of ṝ is not "known" unambiguously is irrelevant; all that matters is that the vowel is used, and pronounced *somehow*, today. After all, all this applies equally well to short ṛ too; would you claim that it isn't used either? Every tradition/region has its own pronunciation of ṛ and ṝ in Sanskrit, and continues to use it. For that matter, even the vowels *e* and *ai* have some confusion in their pronunciation: described as diphthongs in Sanskrit, but used as monophthongs in Hindi. So what? Will you say they are not used too?

Comment: @Ritesh: That section is Wilson is about vowel sandhi, about concurrence of ṝ with *another* ṛ or ḷ. It's irrelevant to whether ṝ is used by itself or not. And my objection is to the line in your answer which says "No, they are not used in any language (not even in Sanskrit)" — this latter part (that ṝ is not used in Sanskrit) is **false**. It is not even "rarely used" (that's true of ḷ, the short one); the long ṝ is used in common words. And again you bring *scripts* like Kharoshthi and Brahmi, which are entirely irrelevant to the *language* (which is a spoken thing).

Comment: @Ritesh: No use of short ṛ in bhrātṝṇām not correct, from any point of view. And Wilson's section is not relevant there, because there's no sandhi happening there. It's a single word. We're not talking of bhrātṛ + ṛṇam ("brother-debt"), but the genitive (6th case) plural bhrātṝṇāṃ ("of brothers").

Comment: @Ritesh: You are talking of a different word altogether, from what I've been saying from the first. I'm *not* talking of the sandhi of two words pitṛ + ṛṇam (note the short 'a' in ṛṇam). I'm talking of the genitive (6th case) plural of an ṛ-ending word, like pitṛ or bhrātṛ or whatever. See [forms of pitṛ](http://sanskrit.inria.fr/cgi-bin/SKT/sktdeclin?lex=SH&q=pitR&t=KH&g=Mas&font=deva) — look at षष्ठी विभक्ति, which goes like:  पितुः पित्रोः पितॄणाम् — in that पितॄणाम् (pitṝṇām), it is wrong to use पितृणाम् (pitṛṇām).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR why dont you post this as an answer.

Comment: @ARi: Ok, I'll post an answer tomorrow or so.